# initial value in radio button django form

Tags: python, django, django-templates

how can I declare initial value of radio button?

form.py

```
YESNO = (
    ('Yes','Yes'),
    ('No', 'No'),
)
class MyForm(forms.Form):
   like = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=YESNO)
```

myhtml.html

```
{{form.like}}
```

i try to put:

```
like = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=YESNO, initial={'Yes':'Yes'})
```

when i run my code, my radio button has not yet selected..

Comment: initial = {'like':'Yes'}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i put the initial value direct in my `views.py`...

```
def myviews(request):
  .....
  form = MyForm({'like':'Yes'})
  ...
```

Comment: for a radio button, this seems to be ok, for other fields, especially those who require user input like text, this will trigger validation.

Comment: -1. This is the `data` parameter, which as Jingo says, triggers validation. Use the `initial` param instead.

Comment: Agreed. Doing this causes things like empty CharFields on the same form to show validation errors on page load rather than after submit.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this should be done in the view, but  the syntax in the accepted answer is incorrect, as it will trigger field validation on all fields *before* submitting the form. Use instead:

```
def myviews(request):
  .....
  form = MyForm(initial={'like':'Yes'})
  ...
```

Answer (score 3):

you can check documentation [forms field initial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#initial).

Answer (score 1):

this is the way it works `initial='N'` which is the first item in the tuple.

`Choices=(('Y','Yes'), ('N','No')
rs_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Choices),initial='N', widget=forms.RadioSelect)`