# How to leave a radio button selected by default according to a Django field?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

File `models.py`:

```
class AbstractRating(models.Model):
    stars = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Rating(AbstractRating):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'calificación del curso'
        verbose_name_plural = 'calificaciones del curso'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course.title
```

I am trying to make a star rating system, the stars are defined in the `stars` field, the problem occurs at the moment of updating any instance of the `Rating` model.

I need to leave a radio button selected by default (`checked`) according to the value of the `stars` field, but I don't know how to do it.

Basically the problem is to set the attribute marked on the correct radio button. 
But I do not know how to do it.

You may have to use templates tags, but I don't know how to do it, I already tried.

***Any solution?***

---

File HTML:

```
<div class="rating-stars">
     <input type="radio" name="stars" value="1" id="1">
     <input type="radio" name="stars" value="2" id="2">
     <input type="radio" name="stars" value="3" id="3">
     <input type="radio" name="stars" value="4" id="4">
     <input type="radio" name="stars" value="5" id="5">
</div>
```

File `views.py`:

```
class RatingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CheckCourseOwnerAndRatingMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Rating
    form_class = RatingForm
    template_name = 'ratings/rating_update_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('courses:list-of-user')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        success_message = 'Se ha editado la reseña con éxito.'
        messages.success(self.request, success_message)

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: you have to send this information to template and use it in template to select radiobutton.

Comment: But how to select the radius? Pass the information is the least, the problem is how I select the radius according to the information sent.

Comment: use `checked="checked"` in `<input type="radio" checked="checked" />` but you will have to use `{% if %}` to check if you set it in correct radiobutton.

Comment: and how should the condition `if` be? It is the problem.

Comment: `<input type="radio" value="1" {% if selected_value==1 %}checked="checked"{% endif %} />` and the same for other elments but with `selected_value==2`, `selecte_value==3`, etc. and you send `selected_value` from view to template. But Django should have `widgets` to generate objects and you shouldn't do it manually.

Comment: Do you know information about those widgets?

Comment: you have all in official documentation - you should read it from first to last page - [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/) and [RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect)

Comment: ok, thanks There are no special widgets for this case?

Comment: Some similar thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578877/initial-value-in-radio-button-django-form I believe this should help.

Comment: did you check RadioSelect ? it is widget for your case.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem! Thank you very much!!! THANKS!!!